# round sum_range of arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Here is my table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | -1.7148 |
| B | 1.3454 |
| B | .3694 |

I am trying to use a singular formula to sum the totals of Col B based on the Values of Col A rounded to 2 digits

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(a:a,unique(a:a),b:b))
```

results in

| Current Result |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 0 |

The issue here is I need these columns rounded before they are summed in order to get this result

| Want Result |
| --- |
| 3 |
| .01 |

Logically it made sense to adjust my formula to..

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(a:a,unique(a:a),round(b:b,2)))
```

but that gives an error -- "Argument must be a range."

Are there any workarounds I can use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(unique(tocol(A:A,1)),lambda(Σ,sum(ifna(filter(round(B:B,2),A:A=Σ)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```cpp
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(B2:B,2),x=A2:A)))
```